# How do I shorten my Rust code to get integer values from regex named capture groups?

Tags: rust

I am completely new to rust. My first rust code is simple text filter application for parsing log file and accumulating some information. Here is my code:

```
//use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::io::{self};
use regex::Regex;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let re_str = concat!(
        r"^\s+(?P<qrw1>\d+)\|(?P<qrw2>\d+)",//qrw 0|0
        r"\s+(?P<arw1>\d+)\|(?P<arw2>\d+)",//arw 34|118
        );
    let re = Regex::new(re_str).unwrap();
    //let mut buffer = String::new();
    //io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buffer)?;
    let buffer = " 0|1 2|3\n 4|5 6|7\n 8|9 10|11\n";

    let mut lines_skipped = 0;

    let mut m_qrw1:i32 = 0;
    let mut m_qrw2:i32 = 0;
    let mut m_arw1:i32 = 0;
    let mut m_arw2:i32 = 0;

    for line in buffer.lines() {
        match re.captures(line) {
            Some(caps) => {
                // I would like to shorten these long lines =>
                let qrw1 = caps.name("qrw1").unwrap().as_str().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
                let qrw2 = caps.name("qrw2").unwrap().as_str().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
                let arw1 = caps.name("arw1").unwrap().as_str().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
                let arw2 = caps.name("arw2").unwrap().as_str().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
                if qrw1 > m_qrw1 {m_qrw1 = qrw1}
                if qrw2 > m_qrw2 {m_qrw2 = qrw2}
                if arw1 > m_arw1 {m_arw1 = arw1}
                if arw2 > m_arw2 {m_arw2 = arw2}
            }
            None => {
                lines_skipped = lines_skipped + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    println!("max qrw1: {:.2}", m_qrw1);
    println!("max qrw2: {:.2}", m_qrw2);
    println!("max arw1: {:.2}", m_arw1);
    println!("max arw2: {:.2}", m_arw2);

    Ok(())
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e32a89603a8970905d19e932d0cbcee0)</sup>

This works as expected, but I think those long chained calls which I created to get integer values of regex named capture groups are a bit ugly. How do I make them shorter/more in idiomatic rust style? I've got an advice to use ? operator instead of `unwrap` calls but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex::Captures` provides a handy [implementation of `Index<&str>`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.9/regex/struct.Captures.html#impl-Index%3C%26%27i%20str%3E). This lets you pull named matches out with `caps[name]`. Combine that with a few `std` APIs and you can write the same code like this:

````rust
use regex::Regex;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let re = Regex::new(concat!(
        r"^\s+(?P<qrw1>\d+)\|(?P<qrw2>\d+)",
        r"\s+(?P<arw1>\d+)\|(?P<arw2>\d+)",
    ))
    .unwrap();
    let names = ["qrw1", "qrw2", "arw1", "arw2"];
    let buffer = " 0|1 2|3\n 4|5 6|7\n 8|9 10|11\n";

    let mut maximums = [0i32; 4];

    for caps in buffer.lines().filter_map(|line| re.captures(line)) {
        for (&name, max) in names.iter().zip(&mut maximums) {
            *max = std::cmp::max(*max, caps[name].parse()?);
        }
    }
    for (&name, max) in names.iter().zip(&maximums) {
        println!("max {}: {:.2}", name, max);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```
````